# Best way to deploy Apostrophe 0.0.5 & 2.0.0 autogenerated files to a cloud provider or similar?

Tags: apostrophe-cms

This questions relates to both, version 0.0.5 and 2.0.0. Apostrophe generates a single hashed `.css` file and corresponding `.js` when minify is set to true.

We are looking to be able to deploy these files to an s3 bucket or similar and have them hosted from there. The way I see the process likely to be is:

- Let apostrophe generate the files, or use some type of command line to generate these files
- Upload the files with some other task to s3
- Hook somehow into the nunjucks helpers that output the css and js link to include the s3 address ( This could also be useful for just changing the URL to cloudfront)

These step should be run as a pre-task to any deployment action, so that once the new version is started these files are already in place.

I know that 2 calls for 2 static assets is not going to kill the nginx server, however I would prefer having them hosted on a cloud provider.

I would like to ask if this is somehow already handled, and if not, how is it handled in production deployments of A2 at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

The [Deploying Apostrophe in the Cloud](http://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/howtos/deploying-apostrophe-in-the-cloud.html) HOWTO should cover most of these items.

Comment: Alex your link does not answer the question, it just states you can use cloudfare, a paid service. What if I have set up my own cdn? how do I customize the assets urls that are automatically generated. Furthermore the bundle generation seems like a solution but it is not available in 0.0.5

Comment: Hi Fotis, 0.5 has reached its end of life for new features, for the most part. We won't be making a change like this to 0.5. 

(Oops, hit enter too soon)

For 2.x, I reckon we'll get around to allowing a CDN to be specified so that the scripts and stylesheets helpers point there when outputting links. However you can copy the bundle to your CDN today, bypass our helpers and output the links yourself.

Comment: ... And that solution would also work for 0.5, if you wish to pursue it. apostrophe:generation creates minified files, you copy them to your CDN of choice, you output your own script and link tags pointing to them and don't bother to call our helpers.

Answer (score 0):

An updated answer: Apostrophe 2.x now supports generating bundles for deployment to S3. The updated [deploying Apostrophe in the cloud](http://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/howtos/deploying-apostrophe-in-the-cloud.html) HOWTO now covers this.